# Cannot convert null to 'bool' because it is a non-nullable value type

Tags: c#, excel

I am creating a for loop to check if the cells are empty for an excel sheet, the error message I am getting is

> An unhandled exception of type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' occurred in Unknown Module.
>   Additional information: Cannot convert null to 'bool' because it is a non-nullable value type.

I tried converting to string as suggested in another thread, but I am unlucky with it.

I am using Microsoft Excel 12.0 Object Library.

Here is my code:

```cs
for (int i = 1; i < 55555; i++)
{
     if (xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, 1] = null)
     {
          //////Write data into the cell 
     }
     else
     {
          //// i++;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be `xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, 1] == null` the single = assigns the value to the cell.

Comment: I tried this before and got this error:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A01A8

Comment: I might be wrong with my structure of my program. Changing it to "==" is also causing me error but not the same, I hope it is different I will look into it thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi, it should be a different problem

Comment: Yes, I understand it now. It actually with the close statement inside the loop. The worksheet was open when I checked in the task manager and I was trying to update it with new data.

Answer (score 1):

```cs
if (xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, 1] = null)
{
     //////Write data into the cell 
}
else
{
     //// i++;
}
```

it's not

```
xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, 1] = null
```

it should be

```
xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, 1] == null
```

`=` is an assignment operator while `==` is used for comparison.